# Yii2 - Retrieving model based on Count in Related Table

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2

This is part of my db schema

[image: Db's schema]

As you can see based on the schema a Vacancy can appear in one or more Faculties. I want to retrieve Vacancies that:

1. Appear only in one Faculty and that Faculty only.
2. Appear in more than one Faculty.

This way I can display Vacancies to their respective Faculty Admin (with the exception for Vacancies that appears on more than one Faculty will be displayed to a special Admin).

I tried using `Vacancy::find()->where()` clause but it seems that `where()` doesn't take `COUNT()` as an argument.

Comment: what you want ? can you write sql query I will help in yii2

Comment: @knowledge.... I also tried the same thing. I can't write it in SQL query too.

Comment: can you show your desire result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for filter an aggregated  result in a query you should use

```
Vacancy::find()
  ->leftJoin('vacancy.id = facultyvacancy.vacancy_id')
  ->having('count(*) = 1')->groupBy('your_column_for_grouping')
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't have access to my pc right now. So I will try this when I have the chance. Btw,  how is that query going to know that it's going to count data from `FacultyVacancy`?